# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

I'm learning how to scrape data using the book *"Visualize This"* by Nathan Yau. I'm trying to scrape Wunderground for the year 2009, but I'm getting this error. It's saying it is out of range, but I don't get why.

```
line 43, in <module>
    f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Below is my code:

```
import sys
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

# Create/open a file called wunder.txt (which will be a comma-delimited file)
f = open('wunder-data.txt', 'w')

# Iterate through months and day
for m in range(1, 13):
  for d in range(1, 32):

  # Check if already gone through month
    if (m == 2 and d > 28):
     break
    elif (m in [4, 6, 9, 11] and d > 30):
     break

  # Open wunderground.com url
  url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2009/" + str(m) + "/" + str(d) + "/DailyHistory.html"
  page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

  # Get temperature from page
  soup = BS(page,"html.parser")
  # dayTemp = soup.body.nobr.b.string
  dayTemp = soup.find("span", text="Mean Temperature").parent.find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip=True)

  # Format month for timestamp
  if len(str(m)) < 2:
    mStamp = '0' + str(m)
  else:
    mStamp = str(m)

  # Format day for timestamp
  if len(str(d)) < 2:
    dStamp = '0' + str(d)
  else:
    dStamp = str(d)

  # Build timestamp
  timestamp = '2009' + mStamp + dStamp

  # Write timestamp and temperature to file
  f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n')

# Done getting data! Close file.
f.close()
```

Comment: try `open('wunder-data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')`

Comment: Thank you! But new problem.    line 6, in <module>
    open('wunder-data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: whoops, just noticed you are on Python2.

Comment: what should I do? I am a newer to Python. Thank you!

Comment: You can use `import io` and then use `io.open('wunder-data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')` instead of built-in `open`. You should consider using Python 3 instead of Python 2 if you are beginning.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem, but a new one came out. Can you help me? Thank you! It said:line 44, in <module>
    f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n')
NameError: name 'f' is not defined

Comment: Even after `f = open('wunder-data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')` ? Did you forget to assign the newly opened file to `f`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is [the degree symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm). That is your `u'\xb0'` character.

[juanpa.arrivillaga's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745224/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xb0-in-position-11/42745342#comment72607575_42745224) is correct that you should use a file encoding. The easiest way to do that in Python 2 is:

```
from codecs import open
```

Then this should be fine:

```
open('wunder-data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

I fear that this isn't the only Unicode or non-ASCII encoding issue that is going to bite you. The world is now Unicode, and Python 3 is **much** better at dealing with Unicode. It can be done in Python 2—but it takes much more care and attention. Nonetheless, the `codecs` module should get you out of the immediate crunch.

Comment: Thank you! But I have a new problem now. Oh, so tired. It said: line 44, in <module>
    f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n')
NameError: name 'f' is not defined

Comment: @XinyaWang Please consider up-voting answers that were helpful to you, and/or marking one of them as "the preferred answer" (by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer).

Answer (score 2):

In this function call:

```
f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n')
```

`timestamp`, `','` and `'\n'` are `str` objects, whereas `dayTemp` is `unicode`.

Sum of `str` and `unicode` is a `unicode` object. Note that this will fail if `str` objects are not only ASCII characters.

In this case, the code actually does something like the following (`\xb0` represents °):

```
f.write(u'20090305,11\xb0\n')
```

The problem with this is that `unicode` characters cannot be directly written to a file. They are just an abstraction and there is not one unique format to write them in<sup>*</sup>. You have to choose one. The best choice is usually UTF-8.

```
s = (timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n').encode('utf-8')
# or, cleaner:
s = u'{},{}\n'.format(timestamp, dayTemp).encode('utf-8')
f.write(s)
```

Another option is to have a *smarter* `file` object which automatically encodes `unicode` to UTF-8, as others have suggested:

```
with io.open('wunder-data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n')
```

or

```
with io.open('wunder-data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n')
```

---

<sup>* Actually, ASCII is the one unique format, but that only works if all characters can be representes in ASCII.</sup>